# Open Text File and Save as SQL file using Python

Tags: python, sql, csv

By using the .replace function, I was able to open a csv file and replace some text within the string, and re save the csv file as a txt file using python. I would now like to save this new txt file (or at leas the string that is in the txt file) as a .sql file.

Code:
    # Read in the file
    with open('Region.txt', 'r') as file :
      filedata = file.read()

```
# Replace the target strings
filedata = filedata.replace("America", "Europe")
filedata= filedata.replace("South America", "East Europe")

# Write the file out again
with open('MyDebt.txt', 'w') as file:
  file.write(filedata)
file.close()
```

Text file: (Region.txt)

```
select country_name from abcd.d_organizations where region = 'America' and region2 = 'South America'
union all
select 'South America' country_name from dual
order by country_name asc
```

Comment: The SQL file (you mean DDL I think) is a text file with syntax that the DBMS that you are dealing with recognizes. So you can take valid SQL from your `Region.txt` and save it to a file, say `Region.SQL` and use that with a DBMS. You might need to add some other DDL to that file to make it do what you want.

Comment: @ShawnMehan can you clarify what DDL and DBMS means?

Comment: @ShawnMehan Okay I understand what you are saying now. Yes, I would like to save the text from my Region.txt (as this is the language my database recongnizes) as a .sql file ( e.g- Region.sql). But how do i do this???    I will need run some separate python code that opens the connection to the DB, runs Regions.sql and writes the output to a dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what I was doing wrong.. pretty simple. Once i make the changes to the .txt file, I need to save immediately save the changes to the text (filedata)to a .sql file instead of to the same .txt file.

```
# Read in the file with open('Region.txt', 'r') as file : filedata = file.read()

# Replace the target strings
filedata = filedata.replace("America", "Europe")
filedata= filedata.replace("South America", "East Europe")

# Write the file out again
with open('Region.sql', 'w') as file:
  file.write(filedata)
```

Comment: Yep. As I wrote, the sql file is really just a txt file with valid SQL in it. BTW, your last `file.close()` is redundant. You don't need it since you appropriately used a context handler to open the file, so you can safely delete that line.